# How to generate a grammar for a given sentence?

Tags: nlp, text-processing, context-free-grammar

I have been asked to generate grammar for a given sentence. Then, convert these grammars into CNF. I understand that CNF conversion process. But I am unable to understand the process of generating grammar (i.e CFG) of a sentence. It would be helpful if someone can explain a step-by-step process to do the same. Thanks

For example, The company was doing great in terms of sales.

Update:
Here are the remaining 3 sentences:
2) The new products and services contributed to increase revenue.
3) Dow falls as recession indicator flashed red due to coronavirus and economical worries continue.
4) He claimed massive nationwide fame because of his gold medal in Olympics.

I want to generate grammar for all non-terminals as well as all lexical terminals n the four sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a grammar for that sentence:

```
START -> The company was doing great in terms of sales.
```

If all you have is one sentence, that's all your grammar needs to be. You could create a more complex grammar to generate that sentence, but there isn't really any point, unless there are aspects of the problem that you haven't stated.

Normally, in a problem where you need to create a grammar, you would be given a larger (possibly infinite) set of sentences that the grammar needs to generate.

Comment: thanks @michael. I have 4 sentences. My end goal is to generate CKY parser. I will convert this CFG grammar to CNF and then use CNF to create CKY parser. I have updated the question with remaining sentences. It would be helpful if you can help me understand how to generate CFG. Thanks

Comment: I understand that we would require huge data, ideally, to create good grammar. My goal hear is just to understand the algorithm. Thanks again.

Comment: Given a finite set of n sentences, you can construct a grammar with n productions by repeating the approach given in my answer. Of course, the grammar will generate *only* those n sentences, but it seems more likely that you want a grammar that generates these sentences *among others*. If so, do you get to choose what other sentences the grammar generates?